# positon element relative to parent.parent container in JS? no absolute/fixed positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

*I have a tough problem where I'm desperately trying to find a working solution.*

A `article#post` and a `aside#sidebar` are floated left side by side - fairly simple.
Inside my `article#post` is a `h1` and a `div.post-entry`.

I wonder if I can somehow determine the relative offset of the `div.post-entry` to the outer container `section#content`. The reason I want to do this is so I can position the floated sidebar with a `margin-top` on the same height as the ´div.post-entry` is.

**Here is a model of my current html structure:**

```
<section id="content">

    <article id="post">
        <h1>Title of the post</h1>
        <div class="post-entry">
            <p>Something</p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <aside id="sidebar>
        Something
    </aside>

</section>
```

So again, I'd like to find any solution to get a pixel-value of how far from the top `div.post-entry` is positioned inside `section#content`.

The main problem I have is that I can't even seem to `post-entry.offsetTop` to work. This should get the offset of `div.post-entry` relative to the `article.post` since this is its parent. That should actually work for me too.

```
var articleOffset = $('.post-entry').offsetTop;
console.log($('.post-entry')); //found and exists
console.log(articleOffset); undefined
```

Any ideas why this does not work for me either? Why do I get undefined for the `offsetTop` value here. There is a big `<h1>` with a padding of at least "30px" that offsets `div.post-entry`.

Any ideas on that matter?
Maybe any other cool solutions on how to do that? I just want to have the `aside#sidebar` starting on the same height as `div.post-entry` but I don't want to change the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the DOM element from the jQuery object.

```
var articleOffset = $('.post-content')[0].offsetTop;
```

Comment: OK, thank you. This doesn't return undefined but the same value as `$('.post-content').offset()` … so `$('.post-content')[0].offsetTop;` somehow returns the offset the element has from the document and not from its parent. I'd like to know the `offsetTop` from within the `article#post` or even the `section#content`.

Comment: Got it. I need to set `position:relative` to the wrapper of the element.